# Caching web page data, Database or File

Tags: asp.net, database, file, caching

I am creating an RSS reader application that requests the RSS from my server. I mean, the RSS is first downloaded to my server, then application downloads it from my server.

I want to create RSS cache for this. And for example, each RSS would be refreshed every 1 minute. So, If 10 users request RSS of example.com in 1 minute, my server will download it only for the first time, and in other 9 requests, RSS will be loaded from cache.

My question is, Should I use a Database (MSSQL) for this purpose? or I should use files?

I have no limit in Database size nor in file size...

**EDIT: I'm using ASP.NET for the server.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net has a build in cache, here is the msdn on best practices for it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx

Comment: Does it cache data into memory? What if I need to cache too many RSS pages?!

Comment: it is memory based, but when you think about it 1mb can hold about 500 pages of text, it's unlikely you would have enough short term cache (1 min) stored to make much of a difference on your system

Comment: Is almost 10 megabytes of data suitable for caching into memory?

Comment: shouldn't be a problem at all

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Memcached](http://memcached.org) for this and set the cache expiry time to be 10 minutes or whatever you want. I found [this](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/07/memcached) for you.

P.S. Google is our friend

Comment: see my edit for your Asp.net needs or better ask someone at #memcached on irc

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't want use RAM for caching?!?

Answer (score 2):

[possible duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059352/caching-moderate-amounts-of-data-in-a-web-app-db-or-flat-files)

Use memcaching and avoid file access since that will be slower.

Comment: But there is some memory limit... Are you sure that memory is better than database?